# Finding specific values in JSON.NET with C#

Tags: c#, json, linq, json.net

I've been making a Minecraft launcher. I have a long JSON file that contains all the libraries required to launch *one* version. A sample of this code:

```
{
  "id": "1.6.2",
  "time": "2013-08-06T14:00:00+03:00",
  "releaseTime": "2013-07-05T16:09:02+03:00",
  "type": "release",
  "minecraftArguments": "--username ${auth_player_name} --session ${auth_session} --version ${version_name} --gameDir ${game_directory} --assetsDir ${game_assets}",
  "libraries": [
    {
      "name": "net.sf.jopt-simple:jopt-simple:4.5"
    },
    {
      "name": "com.paulscode:codecjorbis:20101023"
    },
```

So you can see that there is an array called `libraries`. I can query the values in "name" using a foreach quite fine, but sometimes this occurs in the json:

```
{
  "name": "org.lwjgl.lwjgl:lwjgl:2.9.0",
  "rules": [
    {
      "action": "allow"
    },
    {
      "action": "disallow",
      "os": {
        "name": "osx",
        "version": "^10\\.5\\.\\d$"
      }
    }
  ]
},
```

So as you can see, there is an array inside called `rules`. I need to find the value of `name` inside `os` inside `rules`. Anything I've tried came up with an exception and wouldn't work. This is my code at the moment for parsing the code:

```
    foreach (JToken lib in profilejsono["libraries"])
    {
        if ((lib["rules"][1]["os"].ToString() == "osx") || (lib["rules"][1]["os"].ToString() == "linux"))
        {
            availableLibs.Add(lib["name"].ToString());
        }
    }
```

The point of the code is not to add the library if it's for OSX or Linux (I'll add that functionality later). How do I do this?

Comment: Would you share the exact exception that you get?

Comment: System.NullReferenceException (Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Comment: You get this error because the way you try to reach to the `["os"]` value. The `foreach` loop is returning each `Jtoken` but in fact only one item will return value for `lib["rules"][1]["os"]` otherwise you get `null` because this item just don't have the property `"os"`.

Comment: There are many ways to manage this but the easiest one is just to make some additional check if `lib["rules"].count >= 2`, because you want the second element which has index `[1]` then, check if it has `"os"` property and so on... I don't tell it's the best way, but just to get you on the right track..

Comment: I made it check for anything that has a `rules` element. If it threw an exception that it wasn't found, the program treats it like it's not there. Otherwise it does nothing. I wish I could find another way other than this macgyver'ed method

Comment: My suggestion is to post new question with your working example no matter how bad you think it is and ask for assistance on improving it. In this question you find out why you get this error at first place, if I were you I would ask another question for the best way to deal with this case.

Answer (score 1):

One possible solution to your problem is to generalize the check for the OS name (and make it independant of the rules node depth). I suppose you have some library objects, because you need to deserialize the JSON input string to some object. The following code gives you the library names only for library nodes that have **rule** nodes with **os** nodes with a **specified** name:

JSON Test-Input file *lib1.json*:

```
{
  "name": "lib1",
  "rules": [
    {
      "action": "allow"
    },
    {
      "action": "disallow",
      "os": {
        "name": "windows",
        "version": "^10\\.5\\.\\d$"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

JSON Test-Input file *lib2.json*:

```
{
  "name": "lib2",
  "rules": [
    {
      "action": "allow"
    },
    {
      "action": "disallow",
      "os": {
        "name": "osx",
        "version": "^10\\.5\\.\\d$"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

JSON Test-Input file *lib3.json*:

```
{
  "name": "lib3",
  "rules": [
    {
      "action": "allow"
    },
    {
      "action": "disallow",
      "os": {
        "name": "linux",
        "version": "^10\\.5\\.\\d$"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

JSON Test-Input file *lib4.json*:

```
{
  "name": "lib4",
  "rules": [
    {
      "action": "allow"
    },
    {
      "action": "disallow"
    }
  ]
}
```

JSON helper objects describing the *library* node, needed to deserialize the JSON inputs:

```
// helper classes describing the library object (for the JSON deserialization)
public class Library
{
    public String Name { get; set; }
    public Rules[] Rules { get; set; }
}

public class Rules
{
    public String Action { get; set; }
    public Os Os { get; set; }
}

public class Os
{
    public String Name { get; set; }
    public String Version { get; set; }
}
```

Code for fetching only matching libraries:

```
var jsonInput = @"d:\temp\json.net\lib{0}.json";
try
{
    // load libraries / deserialize json
    var libraries = new List<Library>();
    Enumerable.Range(1, 4).ToList().ForEach(index => 
    {
        var json = File.ReadAllText(String.Format(jsonInput, index));
        libraries.Add(JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Library>(json));
    });
    // OS names to check if present in the current rules
    var osNames = new List<String> { "osx", "linux" };
    // check each library
    foreach (var library in libraries)
    {
        // do we have rules?
        if (library.Rules.Length > 0)
        {
            // get all non-empty OS nodes
            var existingOsNodes = library.Rules.Where (r => r.Os != null).Select (r => r.Os).ToList();
            // check for allowed OS name
            var osIsPresent = existingOsNodes.Where (node => osNames.Contains(node.Name.ToLower())).Select (node => node.Name);
            if (osIsPresent.Any())
            {
                Console.WriteLine(library.Name);
            }
        }
    }
}
catch (Exception e)
{
    Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
}
```

The output for the four given input files is:

```
lib2
lib3
```

Comment: The problem is the general libraries don't have a `rules` element, only `name.

Comment: Soo how can you check for something if it is not present? Please explanation the matter more thoroughly and give more examples in your question.

Comment: What I did was check for an ArgumentNullException, which means it didn't find the specified element. Thus, it's fine. Otherwise, if it does find the `rules` element, it just does nothing.

Comment: The code from my answer works correctly in every situation you described (no matter what node is present and missing). Have you tried it out to see if it works for you?

Comment: No I haven't because I have JSON.NET, so most of your code is irrelevant.

Comment: Then please do so, because if you take your time to read my answer and reflect on it a bit, you will see that i **also use** JSON.NET to load the input and as i see it none of the given code is irrelevant.